# Restrict input length using annotation in java POJO

Tags: java, json, web-services, string-length, annotated-pojos

I have a POJO class like below,

```
    @XmlRootElement
    public class JsonReply {

@XmlElement(nillable = false)
String callResult;

@XmlElement(nillable=false)
String returnobj;

@NotNull
String callError;

public String getCallResult() {
    return callResult;
}

public void setCallResult(String callResult) {
    this.callResult = callResult;
}

public String getCallError() {
    return callError;
}

public void setCallError(String callError) {
    this.callError = callError;
}
```

To avoid a null string I am using many annotations like Lombok's @NotNull and 
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement's @XmlElement(nillable=false). And my question is that Is any other way or annotation to restrict a length for  Integer or String like min=5 and max=10.

```
       @Size(max=10)
       @Max(5)
       Integer sampleint;
```

I am using Jackson. if any annotation is there in Jackson itself like @JsonIgnoreProperties then very fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using bean validation?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin No am not using

Comment: Are you using any particular frameworks for your web services?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin yeah am using Jersey+Jackson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bean Validation

You could consider [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/). It's annotations based and integrates with wide variety of frameworks. The reference implementation is [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

Here are some highlights that may be useful for you:

- For `String` validation, the out-of-the-box annotation you might be interested in is [`@Size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html).
- For number validation, consider [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html), [`@Max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html), [`@DecimalMin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html), [`@DecimalMax`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMax.html) and [`@Digits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Digits.html).
- Use [`@NotNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) to do not accept `null` values.

For more details, check the [`javax.validation.constraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) package.

### Bean Validation and Jersey 2.x

Bean Validation support in Jersey 2.x is provided as an extension module and needs to be mentioned explicitly in your `pom.xml` file (in case of using Maven):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have also all the transitive dependencies (see the [`jersey-bean-validation`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.2/jersey/project/jersey-bean-validation/dependencies.html) artifact) on the classpath. This module depends directly on Hibernate Validator which provides a most commonly used implementation of the Bean Validation specification.

In Jersey, the Bean Validation module is an [auto-discoverable features](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable), that is, it's one of the modules where you don't need to explicitly register it's `Feature`s ([`ValidationFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/ValidationFeature.html)) on the server as it's features are automatically discovered and registered when you add the [`jersey-bean-validation`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.2/jersey/project/jersey-bean-validation/dependencies.html) module to your classpath.

For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about Bean Validation support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html).

Comment: unfortunately am using jersey 1.8. what should I do now?

Comment: @KarthikeyanPandian You still can use Bean Validation/Hibernate Validator. However, AFAIK, there's no out-of-the-box integration with Jersey 1.x. [The documentation mentions nothing about integration with Bean Validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.8/user-guide.html).